Current sensitivity in transformer scheme with SQUID
I've tried to determine the maximum current sensitivity in this transformer scheme but I'm not sure if my solution is valid. I need to find the relation between the current in the input transformer and the flux through the SQUID. At step 3, in my solution below, you can see that I assume that the flux though the second transformer is equal to the flux through the SQUID, is this valid? Is the transfer och flux through the transformers this simple?



Please use MathJax for equations.
